# Why does this recursive function loop infinitely rather than printing numbers in reverse?

Tags: c, recursion

```
int reverse(int);
void main()
{
     int no =5;
     reverse(no);
}

int reverse(int no)
{

 if(no == 0)
      return 0;
else 
 printf("%d",no);

reverse(no--);
}
```

This program goes in infinite loop.Why is that so? I am not able to get the desired ouput.
Desired output should be 5 4 3 2 1.Thank you in advance

Comment: By the way, its supposed to be `int main()`. `void main` is non-portable and doesn't work on all compilers.

Comment: A debugger can come in handy at times like this...

Answer (score 12):

In this recursive call:

```
reverse(no--);
```

You are passing the *value* of `no--`.  Since this uses the postfix -- operator, this means "decrement `no`, then pass the *original* value of `no` into the recursive call to `reverse`."  This causes infinite recursion, since you are constantly making a recursive call with `reverse` set to the same value.

To fix this, change this to read

```
reverse(no - 1);
```

Notice that there's no reason to decrement `no` here, since within the current recursive call you will never read `no` again.  You can just pass the value of `no - 1` into the function.  In fact, you might want to in general avoid using `--` in recursive calls, since it almost always indicates an error in the code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You're using the post-decrement operator on `no`. That first gets the value of `no` and uses that as the value of the expression and *then* decrements `no` (still using the undecremented value as the value of the expression). You probably want to use `--no` or even just `no - 1`. (The former will modify `no`, whereas the latter will not, but it does not matter because `no` is not referenced after that point.)

Comment: I would strongly suggest not using decrement at all - `no` is never being read again, and using decrement probably suggests that the OP misunderstands how `no` is a different variable in each function call.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
reverse(no--);
```

to:

```
reverse(no-1);
```

`no--` returns the original value before the decrement occurred. So this line will always call `reverse(5)`. Hence, infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

`n--` is post increment which first use n as argument of the function and then decrement n.

So `n--` essentially does is

```
reverse(n);
n = n - 1;
```

What you want is `--n`

Answer (score 0):

You are using post-decrement. First evaluates, then reduces value.

Change this:

```
reverse(no--);
```

to this:

```
return reverse(--no);
```

**--no** is pre-decrement. First decrease "no", then pass the value to reverse.

Note that I'm RETURNING the result value, you function always have to return an int, due to its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do

```
int reverse(int);
int main()
{
    int no =5;
    reverse(no);
}

int reverse(int no)
{
    if(no == 0)
        return 0;
    else 
        printf("%d",no);
    return reverse(--no);
}
```

So that you're returning a number every time you call reverse and you decrement no before you use it.